# How to 301 redirect “domain.com/?...” to "domain.com"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

When I visit my "domain.com/?" or "domain.com/?any-other-character-here" it shows my homepage, this caused duplicate results in Google. Web server is Apache.

My code is

`ErrorDocument 404 domain.com/error404.html`

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com`

`RewriteRule (.*) domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?\s`

`RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]`

It redirects non-www to www and I added your code in it. But still see domain.com/?any-random-text doesn't redirect to 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix 404 and problems of `domain.com/?` you can have this rewrite code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/error404.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but Please update your answer to my edited question. This question is more clear about what I need.

Comment: Is that the reason why you removed acceptance mark? In any case my answer still fits the duplicate removal requirement as I am using 301 which will fix dup results.

Comment: Your code only redirects domain.com/? but not domain.com/?...

Comment: Code redirects `domain.com/? ` to `domain.com` and `domain.com/any-random-text` to `http://domain.com/error404.html` (if you don't want custom error handler then you can change that)

Comment: sorry cant read code from comments, can you edit the question and post it there?

Comment: Question is fixed with my code

Comment: ok can you tell me what is your first 301 rule supposed to do?

Comment: It redirects non-www to www and I added your code in it. But still see domain.com/?any-random-text doesn't redirect to 404

Comment: But as you can see in your question there is no `www` in your rules (may be a copy/paste error).

Comment: where? I don't get it

Comment: You mean that change: ErrorDocument 404 domain.com/error404.html to ErrorDocument 404 www.domain.com/error404.html

Comment: Yes that should be made `www` also you need to test this in a new browser.

Comment: It doesn't work, still shows my homepage. only domain.com/? redirects to domain.com. But domain.com/?any-text-here still show my homepage and not 404

Comment: Because `domain.com/?any-text-here` is not a 404 since `any-text-here` is query string and URI is `/` which is valid.

Comment: so what should I do? I have unlimited duplicates for my homepage.

Comment: try updated code in my answer.

Comment: I don't know why you did it for free, but i just could say thank you, totally great job!

Comment: You're welcome, always a pleasure when things work out.

Comment: domain.com/?= doesn't redirect

Comment: oh no , domain.com/?=0 doesn't redirect.